# apache mina sshd authenticate client signatures

Tags: java, sshd, java-security, apache-mina

I'm trying to authenticate a signature that clients generate from their private key and send to the server.

The only authenticator I could find in the library that sounded appropriate was the `PublickeyAuthenticator`. Please correct me if this is the wrong class to do this.

I currently have:

```
this.sshServer.setPublickeyAuthenticator(new PublickeyAuthenticator() {
                @Override
                public boolean authenticate(String username, PublicKey key, ServerSession session) {
                    if (username.equals("client")) {
                         //if signature == valid??
                         return true;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Does anyone know if mina supports signature verification and if so, how can it be implemented?

My understanding is that I'd first have to assign/add the user public key to the server. If the client has provided a `id_rsa.pub` file, how can I go about adding this file to the server as the public key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mina SSH has a few implementations of `PublickeyAuthenticator`.
Look at
`org.apache.sshd.server.config.keys.AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator` and 
`org.apache.sshd.server.auth.pubkey.KeySetPublickeyAuthenticator`.
Implementations of `PublickeyAuthenticator` only check that the given public key is associated with the user.
The actual verification of the signature is handled internally to MINA SSH after the authentication.
The `AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator` only supports one user(it doesnt check the username), but you could for example just point it at your `id_rsa.pub` file and it should work.

```
this.sshServer.setPublickeyAuthenticator(
    new AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator(new File("id_rsa.pub"));
```

You could write your own `PublicKeyAuthenticator` that checks the keys against a map of users like so:

```
public class UserKeySetPublickeyAuthenticator implements PublickeyAuthenticator {
    private final Map<String, Collection<? extends PublicKey>> userToKeySet;

    public UserKeySetPublickeyAuthenticator(Map<String, Collection<? extends PublicKey>> userToKeySet) {
        this.userToKeySet = userToKeySet;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, PublicKey key, ServerSession session) {
        return KeyUtils.findMatchingKey(key, userToKeySet.getOrDefault(username, Collections.emptyList())) != null;
    }

}
```

You need to write some code to populate the map with your key data.
`AuthorizedKeyEntry` has utility methods for doing this from files, inputstreams or strings.
An example of reading from user named authorized key files:

```
Map<String, List<PublicKey>> userKeysMap = new HashMap<>();
List<String> users = Arrays.asList("Jim", "Sally", "Bob");
for(String user : users){
    List<PublicKey> usersKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    for(AuthorizedKeyEntry ake : AuthorizedKeyEntry.readAuthorizedKeys(new File(user + "_authorized_keys"))){
        PublicKey publicKey = ake.resolvePublicKey(PublicKeyEntryResolver.IGNORING);
        if(publicKey != null){
            usersKeys.add(publicKey);
        }
    }
    userKeysMap.put(user, usersKeys);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to register multiple public keys and validate them per user?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example of how you could implement it for multiple users.